# Using stripe payout merchant to customers

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I want to use STRIPE PHP API for creating payments to customers from merchant account.

My Scenario is: I have some products and customers comes to my site and purchase the product but some of the customers will come from the referral code and we need to pay some commission amount to the affiliate customers.

So, for such scenario, I have to payout affiliate users using the stripe payment.

Comment: You want to look into Stripe Connect: https://www.stripe.com/connect and you should talk to their support team to describe your business in more details and they can confirm whether the flow of funds can be supported